# oci_bind_by_name buggy with TO_DATE SQL function

Tags: php, oracle

I have a strange issue today related to the `oci_bind_by_name` function I use in PHP.

Let me give you a showcase.

Here is a table with simple dates:

```
create table test(col1 date);
insert into test values(to_date('01/01/2009','DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into test values(to_date('01/01/2019','DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into test values(to_date('01/01/2029','DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into test values(to_date('01/01/2039','DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Launching this query will result in 2 rows if I bind `:dt_maj_deb` and `:dt_maj_fin` to 01/01/2009 and 01/02/2019 for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
WHERE col1 BETWEEN TO_DATE (:dt_maj_deb, 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
               AND TO_DATE (:dt_maj_fin, 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Results
-------
01.01.2009          
01.01.2019
```

So everything is as we may expect. My concern is when I want to launch the same query from PHP. Here is my test code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TEST 
          WHERE col1 BETWEEN TO_DATE (:dt_maj_deb, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                         AND TO_DATE (:dt_maj_fin, 'DD/MM/YYYY')";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
$value = '01/01/2009';
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':dt_maj_deb',$value);
$value = '01/02/2019';
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':dt_maj_fin',$value);
oci_execute($stmt);
oci_fetch_all($stmt, $result);
var_dump($result);
oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);

Results
-------
array(1) {
    ["COL1"]=>
       array(0) {}
}
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you binding both `:dt_maj_deb` and `:dt_maj_fin` to the same `$value`, so when you execute they'll both hold the same date? As there are no data actually on 01/02/2019 there is nothing to return. If your second `$value=` was to a date that does exist in the table then you'd get exactly one row back, wouldn't you? Or, to put it another way, use different variables for the two `oci_bind_by_name()` calls.

Comment: Thank you Alex, once again I were tricked by the oci library, not the first time... I hope it was the last :)